# What's a binary file and how do I create one?

Tags: c, linux, binaryfiles

I would like to create a binary file representing an integer. I think the file should be 4 bytes. I use linux. How to do that?
Another question: How do I assign the content of that file to an integer in C?

Answer (score 16):

In standard C, `fopen()` allows the mode `"wb"` to write (and `"rb"` to read) in binary mode, thus:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    /* Create the file */
    int x = 1;
    FILE *fh = fopen ("file.bin", "wb");
    if (fh != NULL) {
        fwrite (&x, sizeof (x), 1, fh);
        fclose (fh);
    }

    /* Read the file back in */
    x = 7;
    fh = fopen ("file.bin", "rb");
    if (fh != NULL) {
        fread (&x, sizeof (x), 1, fh);
        fclose (fh);
    }

    /* Check that it worked */
    printf ("Value is: %d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
Value is: 1
```

Comment: keep this in mind (via man fopen): The  mode  string  can also include the letter 'b' either as a last character or as a character between the characters in any of
       the two-character strings described above.  This is strictly for compatibility with C89 and has no effect; the 'b' is ignored on
       all POSIX conforming systems, including Linux.  (Other systems may treat text files and binary files differently, and adding the
       'b' may be a good idea if you do I/O to a binary file and expect that your program may be ported to non-Unix environments.)

Comment: for `float` use this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4465303

Answer (score 4):

From the operating system's point of view, all files are binary files. C (and C++) provide a special "text mode" that does stuff like expanding newline characters to newline/carriage-return pairs (on Windows), but the OS doesn't know about this.

In a C program, to create a file without this special treatment, use the "b" flag of fopen():

```
FILE * f = fopen("somefile", "wb" );
```

Answer (score 3):

Open the file for binary read/write. fopen takes a `b` switch for file access mode parameter - [see here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/)

See the [fopen page in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fopen) for the difference between text and binary files as well as a code sample for writing data to a binary file

Answer (score 2):

See `man` for syscalls `open`, `write` and `read`.