# How can we scan a 100 bytes from STDIN in one go in C++

Tags: c++, string, io, inputstream

The scanner waits till we enter 100 bytes of data. So if we are redirecting a file into the 
executable's input, if the file has > 100 bytes of data. I scan it at one go, rather than line by line with `fgets()` or `scanf("%s")` etc.

Comment: fread() is the function you are looking for.

Comment: Related: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8589425/827263

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fread` to read the number of bytes you want, independent of line breaks or other whitespcae:

```
char buf[100];
size_t bytes_read = fread(buf, 1, 100, stdin);
```

Note that `buf` will not be null-terminated. So if you want to `printf` it, for instance (it needs a null terminated string), you can try the following:

```
char buf[101];
size_t bytes_read = fread(buf, 1, 100, stdin);
buf[100] = '\0'; // The 101th "cell" of buf will be
                 // the one at index `100` since the
                 // first one is at index `0`.
```