# in C, fwrite()'s "size_t size" and "size_t n items" confusion

Tags: c, linux, file, struct, io

So I was trying to write something to stdout from my p->payload which is supposed to be a pointer to a data. And block_size is 256.

My problem is my stdout would always be exactly the same if I switch p->block_size and sizeof(char). Can someone tell my why? Thanks.

```
fwrite(p->payload, p->block_size,sizeof(char),stdout);
```

Comment: See also ["How does fread really work?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8589425/827263)

Comment: Note that with the arguments `p->block_size` and `sizeof(char)`, unless `p->block_size` is `1`, reversing the order of the arguments changes the value returned by `fwrite()`.  It reports the number of items of the given size that were written, so in one case you'll get `p->block_size` returned on success (and 0 on error), and in the other you'll get `1` returned on success (and 0 on error).

Answer (score 3):

The difference is the value that it returns.

`fwrite` returns the number of data elements written.

If you execute

```
count = fwrite(ptr, 1, N, stdout);
```

then `count` will contain the exact number of bytes successfully written. If you do:

```
count = fwrite(ptr, N, 1, stdout);
```

then `count` will contain `1` if the entire write succeeded, or `0` if *any* of it failed.

The distinction may be useful if you need to distinguish between partial success and complete failure. If a partial write is no better than not writing anything at all, you can use the second form.

(There's not likely to be any significant difference in performance.)

See also [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8589425/827263) about `fread`.

Answer (score 2):

In general, just assume `size * items` bytes will be written.

This seems to be an attempt to mirror the `fread` API, which also has `size` and `bytes` parameters. For `fread`, this is more useful, as (for instance) you can ask it to read one item of 1000 bytes--meaning, "I want exactly 1000 bytes"--or you can ask it to read 1000 items of one byte apiece--meaning "I'll take up to 1000 bytes; less data than that is OK." Obviously, lots of useful combinations can be used here if your data being read is fixed-size.

In the case of `fwrite`, though, the only time you'd expect less than `size * items` bytes to be written would be in an error condition. In the case of "disk full" errors, you could hypothetically choose `size` and `items` such that you write as many complete items as possible, but never write a half-item; however, I've never seen anyone actually write code that works this way and doesn't just fail on disk full.

Answer (score 0):

According to `fwrite(3)`:

```
size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

> The function `fwrite()` writes *nmemb* elements of data, each *size* bytes long, to the stream pointed to by *stream*, obtaining them from the location given by *ptr*.

This means `fwrite()` will write 'size * nmemb' bytes from `ptr` to `stream`, because 'size * nmemb' equals 'nmemb * size', so you have the same number of bytes written to `stream` after switched `size` and `nmemb`.