# Segmentation fault without defining an unused array

Tags: c, arrays, linux, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a simple program to output in hex the first 16 kilobytes of a binary file (Game Boy ROM) in 16-bit chunks. However during the `for` loop my program will invariably segfault, however it always segfaults at a different point in the array. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main ()
{
    uint16_t buffer[8000];
    FILE* ROM = fopen("rom.gb", "rb");
    if (ROM == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        fclose(ROM);
        return 1;
    }
    fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, ROM);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); ++i)
    {
        if (buffer[i] < 16)
        {
            printf("000%x ", buffer[i]);
        }
        else if (buffer[i] < 256)
        {
            printf("00%x ", buffer[i]);
        }
        else if (buffer[i] < 4096)
        {
            printf("0%x ", buffer[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%x ", buffer[i]);
        }
    }
    fclose(ROM);
    return 0; 
}
```

Before I changed to using uint16_t instead of char (since the Game Boy has a 16-bit address space) this did not occur, and in fact if I include the declaration

```
unsigned char buffer2[16000];
```

next to the declaration of the first buffer I get the expected output. So my questions are, why would adding an unused variable stop the program from segfaulting? And how can I avoid having to do this and declaring a huge array which is entirely unused in the program?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this line:

```
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); ++i)
```

`sizeof(buffer)` is the size of array in bytes, if you want the number of elements use

`i < (sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0]))`

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the problem and I no longer get segfaults during the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you're using `fread` properly, if you look at the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/), the second argument is the size of each element, whereas you're passing the size of the whole buffer.

You probably want to swap the second and third arguments, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589425/how-does-fread-really-work) for usage examples.

Also note as pointed out by Alter Mann, that you need to divide the size of the buffer by the size of its type.

Comment: This was also helpful, thank you. I changed that line to `fread(buffer, 2, (sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0])), ROM);` which gives the same output but should be more correct. I'm surprised it was even working properly considering how badly I was misusing the function.