# fread() leaves data unread near the end of file

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to read data from a file into a buffer and write it into another file (essentially copying a file). But when i change `BUFFSIZE` to some bigger number, it leaves some content unread near the end of the file, meaning it does not copy the last couple of words into `outfile`

```
#define BUFFSIZE 50
int main(void)
{
    void *buffer = (void *)(malloc(BUFFSIZE));

    FILE *file = (fopen("file.txt", "r"));
    FILE *outfile = (fopen("out.txt", "w"));

    while (fread(buffer, BUFFSIZE, 1, file))
        fwrite(buffer, BUFFSIZE, 1, outfile);

    free(buffer);
    fclose(outfile);
    fclose(file);
}
```

It works fine when i set `BUFFSIZE` to 1. My file isn't that big, around 20 lines of text. Why is this happening?

Comment: Reverse the `BUFSIZE` and `1` parameters.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8589688/827263

Comment: @ikegami "writes too much"??  `fread(buffer, BUFFSIZE, 1, file)` expected to return 0 or 1.  How is 1 too much?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica fread returns the number of items read

Comment: @Nightmare247 Yes, `fread()` does return  number of items read, which in this case is 0 or 1.  How does returning 1 write too much, as suggested by the (deleted) ikegami comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

(1) The call

```
fread(buffer, BUFFSIZE, 1, file)
```

says you want to read up to 1 item of size 50, and it will return how many of them it read, which will be either 0 or 1.  But you want

```
fread(buffer, 1, BUFFSIZE, file)
```

which will read up to 50 items (individual bytes) of size 1, and will return how many of them it read, which will be any number from 0 to 50.

See also [How does fread really work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589425/how-does-fread-really-work)

(2)  You only want to write as many bytes as `fread` read.  So you want to capture `fread's` return value:

```
size_t r;
while ((r = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFSIZE, file)))
    fwrite(buffer, 1, r, outfile);
```